# React, how to make state work between childs?

Tags: reactjs, state

I am trying to figure out how to make a searchFilter work. Here is my situation:
In App.js I hold a state for my items that i get from an api.
I also hold a state for the SearchFilter.

The items arrive and I can render them just fine.
Further, in App.js, I render the items and also a search component. So my code looks something like this:

```
const App = () => {
const [items, setItems] = useState([])
const [searchFilter, setSearchFilter] = useState("")

useEffect(() => {
  const fetchItems = async () => { 
  // FETCHING ITEMS AND SETTING VIA setItems...
  // This part works as expected
}
fetchItems()
},[])

return (
  <>
    <SearchBar setSearchFilter={setSearchFilter} />
    <RenderItems items={items} searchFilter={searchFilter} />
  </>
)
}
```

The problem I face is, that the searchFilter remains undefined in the RenderItems component. Why?
It gets updated correctly in App.js, but somehow doesn't make it's way to RenderItems

Inside component SearchBar:

```
const SearchBar = ({setSearchFilter}) => {
  return (
    <>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Search" onChange={(e) => setSearchFilter(e.target.value) }/ >
    </>
)
{
```

Any clues?

Comment: are you sure you are referring to the exact identifier ? as it should give you `""` which is default value than `undefined` I suppose

Answer (score 2):

Thank you all for the replies @Mandeep Kaur and @KcH
I found the problem was in the data that came from the api when trying this scenario out in a codesandbox.
I keep the link here for future reference: https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-booth-p1tqsv?file=/src/App.js

Closed from my side.

Answer (score 1):

I think this happens because `RenderItems` component is not re-render after updating the state in `SearchBar` component.
You can try with adding one `useEffect` that makes it re-render and it gives the latest data to `RenderItems`

```
useEffect(() => {

},[searchFilter])
```

I am assuming that the updated value you getting in the App.js file.